# pydub: how to retain headroom across `export` and `from_file`?

Tags: python, audio, pydub, normalizing

What are the proper `ffmpeg` flags to pass through `pydub.AudioSegment.export` and / or `pydub.AudioSegment.from_file` to ensure the audio retains the expected headroom?

I'm trying to write some unit tests that assert that audio normalization is taking place as expected, but I'm finding that when I re-open an exported file, the `max_dBFS` is different than it was just before exporting:

```
In [1]: from pydub import AudioSegment, effects, utils
   ...: audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test_input.mp3")
   ...: print(f"Max dB before normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio = effects.normalize(audio, headroom=5)
   ...: print(f"Max dB after normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio.export("test_output.mp3")
   ...: audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test_output.mp3")
   ...: print(f"Max dB of re-opened file: {audio.max_dBFS}")
Max dB before normalizing: 0.0
Max dB after normalizing: -4.99990598233068
Max dB of re-opened file: -2.778919494135808
```

My first thought is this has to do with exporting a fixed bitrate of `"320k"`, but even when I control for the bitrate (which helps a lot), it's still not matching satisfactorily:

```
In [2]: audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test_input.mp3")
   ...: print(f"Max dB before normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio = effects.normalize(audio, headroom=5)
   ...: print(f"Max dB after normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio.export("test_output.mp3", bitrate=utils.mediainfo("test_input.mp3")['bit_rate'])
   ...: audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test_output.mp3")
   ...: print(f"Max dB of re-opened file: {audio.max_dBFS}")
Max dB before normalizing: 0.0
Max dB after normalizing: -4.99990598233068
Max dB of re-opened file: -4.425849083800531
```

Here's an example with a generator so you don't need an actual input file to repro:

```
In [3]: from pydub import AudioSegment, effects, generators, utils
   ...: audio = AudioSegment.silent(duration=1000).overlay(
   ...:     generators.WhiteNoise().to_audio_segment(duration=1000).apply_gain(-2)
   ...: )
   ...: print(f"Max dB before normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio = effects.normalize(audio, headroom=5)
   ...: print(f"Max dB after normalizing: {audio.max_dBFS}")
   ...: audio.export("test_output.mp3")
   ...: audio = AudioSegment.from_file("test_output.mp3")
   ...: print(f"Max dB of re-opened file: {audio.max_dBFS}")
Max dB before normalizing: -2.0005164576636596
Max dB after normalizing: -4.99990598233068
Max dB of re-opened file: 0.0
```

Comment: Might you be able to offer any suggestions, [Jiaaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2908/jiaaro)?